# How could I make a Facebook post more visible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, profile

I need to share, on my personal profile, the fact that I am not reachable via telephone and since it is important for my peers I would like to make the post more visible. There used to be this option of putting a star so that it appears on top of my friends' Newsfeed, but is there any available option now?

I am willing to pay to make it more visible, if this is possible for a personal profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the add to story feature, where you can put text or images to your story to show it up top. You could also set your profile description to the message you want. That's at the very top, right below your profile picture. There's a 200 character limit though.